# My DSLR appears to be corrupting CF cards — get new camera or repair?

Tags: canon, repair, troubleshooting, data-corruption, cfcard

I have a Canon Rebel XTi which has been ruining CF cards (when I try to see the pictures it tells me the CF card is corrupted--three different cards which were formatted). Anyway I want to know if I should bother getting it repaired or just get a new one.

Also, if I get a new one, what about a refurbished one from Canon?

Comment: Hi Marjorie! Welcome to Stack Exchange. It works best if you ask individual questions separately — I'd suggest splitting the Q about buying refurbished out as a new question of its own.

Comment: Can you verify that the cards were formatted using that camera (vs. in a card reader)?  It makes a difference.

Comment: Can you view the "corrupted" cards on the camera? does the camera still see the pictures on them?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your budget. If your camera is in warrantee you may actually be able to get a free repair from canon.

*Budget: $500 and under*

I would recommend buying a used camera. Any old camera used will do: canon 50d, canon xt, etc.

As long as the person hasn't used registered their camera warantee you're in good shape. I would inspect any pictures etc. Or ask about the shutter count.

*Budget: $500+*

Buy refurbished from canon.

Answer (score 1):

What tests have you done to check out the camera & CF cards?

Would strongly suggest either checking the CF cards in another camera or borrow a known working CF card from someone and try it in your own camera.  You may find your local camera store may help you out there as they would win a potential customer either way, a new camera or a new CF card.

Remember that CF cards DO have a limited life and if your photography is important to you then they should always be replaced at first signs of problems.

Certainly seems strange that the camera would semi-fail in such a way, normally this type of electronics would either work or not work, rather than half function.

Comment: looks like it's failing consistently, writing corrupt data. Which could point to a loose contact for one of the pins.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem last time. That too after a photoshoot. I could not read the card with the card reader or the camera itself. I use a Canon Rebel XT. But one format (OUCH!) and it was back up and running. Format should be on the camera itself. Also, after transfer of pictures make sure that you format the card in the camera. This should work fine. If it does not you can either try to fix the firmware or chuck the camera and pick up a new one. The choice would be ultimately yours.